# Test whether complex conjugate is available

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a very long list `ss`, and I want to make sure that all complex numbers and their conjugates exist inside the list. Below is a representative example.

```
ss1 = Table[RandomComplex[], {10}]
ss2 = Conjugate[ss1];
ss = Join[{ss1, ss2}] // Flatten;
cnt=Count[MemberQ[ss, Conjugate[#]] & /@ ss, False]
```

The problem with the above code is that it takes very long time. The length of my `ss` is around 80k. Is there a better and faster approach to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Does the list only have complex numbers?

Comment: yes, only complex numbers.

Comment: "I want to make sure that all complex numbers and their conjugates exist inside the list."  Really?  Check whether an infinity of complex numbers ("all complex numbers") are in the list??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = 10000;
ss1 = Table[RandomComplex[], {n}];
ss2 = Conjugate[ss1];
ss = Join[{ss1, ss2}] // Flatten;
```

You can also (1) check  if `Complement[ss, Conjugate[ss]]` is empty or (2) check if `Sort[ss] == Sort[Conjugate[ss]]`:

```
Count[MemberQ[ss, Conjugate[#]] & /@ ss, False] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {33.556, 0}

```
Complement[ss, Conjugate[ss]] == {} // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.01559, True}

```
Sort[ss] == Sort[Conjugate[ss]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0., True}

With `n = 80000` we get:

```
Sort[ss] == Sort[Conjugate[ss]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.078646, True}

Comment: Wonderful, Thanks

Comment: @qahtah, my pleasure.Thank you for the accept.